# bundle install fails on rugged but 'gem install rugged' works

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redhat, gitorious

I am trying to install Gitorious on Redhat 5. I am following these instructions: https://gitorious.org/gitorious/pages/Rhel_Installation

One of the steps is: rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production

That command fails with the foll error message:

```
[ gitorious ] sudo  rake db:create RAILS_ENV=production
Could not find libdolt-0.33.14 in any of the sources
Run `bundle install` to install missing gems.
```

When I ran 'bundle install' it fails with:

```
0:  makeup (0.4.4) from /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/specifications/makeup-0.4.4.gemspec

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /usr/local/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for gmake... yes
checking for cmake... yes
 -- cmake .. -DBUILD_CLAR=OFF -DTHREADSAFE=ON -DBUILD_SHARED_LIBS=OFF -DCMAKE_C_FLAGS=-fPIC
Package zlib was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `zlib.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
Package 'zlib', required by 'libgit2', not found
 -- /usr/bin/gmake
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of necessary
libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more details.  You may
need configuration options.

Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=/usr/local/bin/ruby
        --with-git2-dir
        --without-git2-dir
        --with-git2-include
        --without-git2-include=${git2-dir}/include
        --with-git2-lib
        --without-git2-lib=${git2-dir}/
extconf.rb:16:in `sys': ERROR: '/usr/bin/gmake' failed (RuntimeError)
        from extconf.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in <main>'
        from extconf.rb:54:in `chdir'
        from extconf.rb:54:in `block in <main>'
        from extconf.rb:51:in `chdir'
        from extconf.rb:51:in `<main>'

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/rugged-5f1b6d177132 for inspection.
Results logged to /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/bundler/gems/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0-static/rugged-0.19.0/gem_make.out
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:89:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:37:in `block in build'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/tempfile.rb:324:in `open'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/ext_conf_builder.rb:17:in `build'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:161:in `block (2 levels) in build_extension'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `chdir'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:160:in `block in build_extension'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `synchronize'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:159:in `build_extension'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:198:in `block in build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/ext/builder.rb:195:in `build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/site_ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/installer.rb:677:in `build_extensions'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/source/path.rb:174:in `generate_bin'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/source/git.rb:161:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:111:in `block in install_gem_from_spec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/rubygems_integration.rb:150:in `with_build_args'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:110:in `install_gem_from_spec'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:265:in `block in install_sequentially'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb:171:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/2.0.0/forwardable.rb:171:in `each'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:264:in `install_sequentially'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:97:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/installer.rb:15:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:255:in `install'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/command.rb:27:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/invocation.rb:121:in `invoke_command'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor.rb:363:in `dispatch'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/vendor/thor/base.rb:440:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/cli.rb:10:in `start'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/bin/bundle:20:in `block in <top (required)>'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/lib/bundler/friendly_errors.rb:5:in `with_friendly_errors'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.0.0/gems/bundler-1.5.2/bin/bundle:20:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/bundle:23:in `<main>'
An error occurred while installing rugged (0.19.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install rugged -v '0.19.0'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I did do 'sudo gem install rugged -v '0.19.0'` and it works:

```
[ gitorious ]  sudo gem install rugged -v '0.19.0'
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
Successfully installed rugged-0.19.0
Parsing documentation for rugged-0.19.0
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for ../../extensions/x86_64-linux/2.0.0-static/rugged-0.19.0/rugged/rugged.so, skipping
unable to convert "\x80" from ASCII-8BIT to UTF-8 for lib/rugged/rugged.so, skipping
1 gem installed
```

I tried 'sudo bundle install --verbose' again but it fails the same way.

I then created a  /usr/lib/pkgconfig/zlib.pc file and did a setenv of the PKG_CONGIF_PATH to add /usr/lib/pkgconfig.

zlib.pc:

```
prefix=/usr
exec_prefix=/usr
libdir=/usr/lib
includedir=/usr/include
sharedlibdir=/usr/lib
Name: zlib
Description: zlib compression library
Version: 1.2.3
Requires:
Libs: -L${libdir} -L${sharedlibdir} -lz
Cflags: -I${includedir}
```

I ran 'sudo bundle install --verbose' and it fails the same way...

The 'Gemfile' is in the main gitorious directory.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

You're missing dependencies. I don't know the entirety of what you need, but based on `libdolt` and `libgit2` you would need the following:

```
yum install python-devel libicu-devel zlib-devel
```

Comment: Tried that. yum didn't install anything new. I did 'rpm -qa|grep zlib' to verify. Ran 'bundle install' again, got the same zlib-related error...

Comment: The only reason is that I noticed the 'bundle install' and 'gem install' are installing libraries in /usr/ directories.Is that a problem, by running with 'sudo'?

Answer (score 0):

If I am not wrong, there were many changes made to [rugged](https://github.com/libgit2/rugged) later on, and it caused some version problem with cmake.

Installing latest cmake version, fixed similar problem for me. Try:

```
yum install cmake
```